# How to invoke a command in PowerShell and get the output without having to wait for completion?

Tags: command-line, powershell, stdout

I use the following code to run a command and get the output :

```
$result = Invoke-Command { .\SomeExecutable.exe }
Write-Output $result
```

It works but major issue is that I have to wait for completion (which take several minutes) before getting any result. If instead I use :

```
Invoke-Command { .\SomeExecutable.exe }
```

This is much better (as soon as one line is outputted by the program, it's written inside PowerShell console).

The downside is that I cannot have that output stored in a variable anymore.
Ideally I would like something like this :

```
foreach($line in Invoke-Command { ... })
{
    Write-Output $line
    //do something with $line
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command
[Tee-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.2)
(tee):

> Saves command output in a file or variable and also sends it down the pipeline.

Use as :

```
.\SomeExecutable.exe | Tee-Object -Variable result
```

Comment: I tried your code : it fails and complains that `$result` is an empty string. If I put something into it (eg: `"foo"`) : the output is printed to console but `$result` stay as it is (`$result = "foo"`).

Comment: Try it without the $, as above.